# <body> position: relative, inline VS .css-file (IE7)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

Im experiencing some really wierd behaviour in IE7. I want to position my `<body>` -tag relative.

If i type

```
body { position: relative; }
```

in my css file, my menu (which is position: absolute) doesn't work. But if i use

```
<body style="position: relative;">
```

It works. How can that possibly make a difference? There is not javascript that is removing the css attribute or something like that.

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference. There must be something else at work here.

Comment: maybe in your css is two body defined that the last one was appear to body.

Comment: Okay so u say IE7, is it same with other browser also?

Comment: @NagarajTantri It works fine in other browsers without the position:relative anywhere. So i guess its an ie7 issue

Comment: @perdickss Thanks but ive checked for that as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was curious about this, but as the question stands @thirtydot's comment seems to be correct: the answer is that there is no difference. I've created [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3EWeX/2/) which renders as expected in IE7 (to be completely honest: I tested it with IE7 mode in IE9).

Here's the code:

```
<html><head></head>
    <body>
        <div class="menu">HOME | PRODUCTS | ABOUT</div>
        <p>Testing!</p><p>Testing!</p><p>Testing!</p><p>Testing!</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

The relevant CSS, with a few colors to visualize things:

```
html {
    background-color: green;
}

div.menu {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    background-color: silver;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
}

body {
    background-color: pink; 
    width: 90%;
    position: relative;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
}
```

Gives me, as expected:

[image: Screenshot from the jsfiddle]

It renders similar in IE9 and FF for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the test. But there are some differences between ie7-mode and native ie7. I spotted the problem on my dedicated ie7 machine running windows xp.