# button selector in ie7 (html5 doctype)

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer

Im having some trouble targeting my buttons in ie7. Doesnt this work with an html5 doctype?

```
 input[type="button"] { color: red; }
```

only

```
input { color: red; }
```

works, but thats not really what im after...

Thanks

Edit: this is a native ie7 problem. ie7-mode works in ie9.

Comment: What exactly are you asking for?

Comment: @iambriansreed A working css selector to target buttons in ie7, with a html5 doctype.

Comment: I'm reminded of your [previous question from yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564903/body-position-relative-inline-vs-css-file-ie7), where something is mysteriously wrong with your genuine IE7. I think there's a *problem* with your IE7, but I can't guess what it could be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `<button></button>` instead of `<input type="button" />`. You then will be able to use element selector (`BUTTON`) instead of attribute selector (`INPUT[type="button"]`).

And, just in case, of course, you cannot select `BUTTON` elements with `INPUT[type="button"]` selector, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

The attribute selector `input[type=button]` is a component of CSS level 2.1, the HTML-type (whether 4.x, or 5) is more or less irrelevant. However the most important factor is that implementation depends on the browser, and its level of CSS compliance/support.

Specifically, according to [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t31), the 'advanced attribute selectors' are not implemented by IE < 7 (which doesn't really address your difficulty in this case).

In my own implementations I've occasionally found issues when quoting the value of the attribute-value, usually fixed by amending the selector to, in this case: `input[type=button]`, but I've performed no objective tests to validate this approach and is based purely on memory.

References:

- [CSS 2.1 selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors).

Answer (score 0):

Note: IE7 and IE8 support attribute selectors only if a !DOCTYPE is specified. Attribute selection is NOT supported in IE6 and lower.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp

Answer (score 0):

> Doesnt this work with an html5 doctype?

A doctype may prevent/allow something to work, but it won't implement something which isn't already inherently supported by the browser. I think that's what you meant; just clarifying.

IE7 does support such selectors: [CSS Selector for <input type="?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470702/css-selector-for-input-type)

As far as I know, every CSS selector works with the HTML 5 doctype (assuming there are no overriding factors, such as compatibility mode).

I can confirm that (at least in IE9) attribute selectors still work in compatibility view. However, forcing quirks mode defeats attribute selectors (and causes general anarchy on a well-structured page).

Comment: Hmm, obviously not all versions of ie7 then?

Comment: There may be another factor. I don't have native IE7 to test, but there is a great deal of information suggesting that it *does* work. Maybe post a JS fiddle which does not work in IE7?